# Proposed Q: How should IT Security data be visualized?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have a rough outline of a question that I don't know how to articulate and keep it on topic.

Basically I'm very interested in how various chart formats can help visualize data that is useful to IT Security Operations.  As I come up with this question I realised many sub questions:

- What types of data should be graphed?
- What graph formats would be used?  Area, Bar, pie, or line chart?
- When would advanced graphs be of use: Radar charts, polar charts, or even a re-purposing of a "financial" chart

Is it necessary that I reign in my focus beyond "Charts valuable to IT Security Operations", since that is a pretty broad area?

Some IT Security charts could be:

- Login failures by source IP, and username
- Inbound TCP connection count / average duration (detect DDOS)

What other constructive criticism is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Too broad and unanswerable IMHO. Any dataset can be visualized in a wide variety of ways, there is nothing peculiar to IT Security.

In fact, it's not the type of chart that is important, but the ability to spot anomalies/outliers and to drill down information on them.